# present perfect with 'When'

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

I've been wondering which of the sentences below is gramatically correct.

1) When it has compeletely destroyed you, grief will be there.
2) When it has compeletely destroyed you, grief is there.

Comment: It would be confusing to use the future tense if you're referring to the present, and it would be confusing to use the present tense if you're referring to the future. But in terms of *grammar*, I don't see a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Elena, use the word “When” and ask a question as opposed to using “When” to communicate cause and effect.

Let’s look at your example sentences. When it has completely destroyed you, grief will be/is there. This is a cause and effect error.

Cause and effect correction: His grief destroyed him, or he grieved and his grief destroyed him.
When as a question: When did he grieve? When did grief destroy him?

When is always a question about time as opposed to an explanation about a condition or cause and effect.

Comment: There is no error in the question. _When_ refers to time in the example sentences, and _when_ is not only used in questions in general. In fact, I have no idea where you’re getting this ‘cause and effect’ business from, nor how it relates to the question. It certainly doesn’t answer the question (but since the question is not really on-topic to begin with, I don’t think it should be answered here).